# SQL: Do all attributes in a GROUP BY clause need to be listed in the SELECT clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, mysql-workbench

Say I have a table called Employee with attributes Name, Salary, Department.

I know that this will work:

```
SELECT Department, AVG(Salary)
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY Department;
```

Would it be incorrect to discard 'Department' from the SELECT clause like so:

```
SELECT AVG(Salary)
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY Department;
```

Or would it still work?

Comment: `AVG(Salary)` is still the same, but, using the second query, you will not know what department each average salary is related to.

Comment: Try it and see if it works.

Comment: You need to read an introduction to SQL. Also, when asking questions explain exactly what you mean by things like "would it still work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both queries will work and provide the output. However, second query will only result in one column (i.e. average salary) and hence, you won't be able to trace it back to department id from second query alone, e.g.:

Query 1 output:

```
dept | salary
1    | 5000
2    | 6000
```

Query 2 output:

```
salary
5000
6000
```

Answer (score 0):

no, not necessarily. You can use the 2nd query too.But you can't see for which depart the salary got sorted by 'group-by' key-word.